# Map custom value field to x value when using a stacked layout

Tags: javascript, layout, svg, stack, d3.js

I successfully mapped y values, but I'm having trouble mapping an x value to an arbitrary field on my values when creating a stacked bar graph using the [stack layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout). I'm not really familiar with Javascript and d3; so I'm probably missing something basic here.

A value in my array of data looks like `{ "xInit": 0, "yInit": 91 }`. I want to map `xInit` to `x` in the graph and `yInit` to `y`.

This works ([suggested by Bryan Clark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512613/322283)):

```
var st = d3.layout
           .stack()
           .values(function (d) { return d.values; })
           .y(function (v, i) { return v.yInit; })
           .out(function (d, y0, y) { d.x = d.xInit; d.y0 = y0; d.y = y; });
```

[image: This works, the x coords are taken from value.xInit]

And this doesn't:

```
var st = d3.layout.stack()
           .values(function (d) { return d.values; })
           .y(function (v, i) { return v.yInit; })
           .x(function (v, i) { return v.xInit; });
```

[image: Fail! value.x returns NaN]

It gives the following warnings:

```
Unexpected value translate(NaN,0) parsing transform attribute.
Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute.
```

Am I using `stack.x([accessor])` incorrectly here? How should I use it then?

*Details*

A complete example showing my problem is available as a [block](http://bl.ocks.org/3103475) based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3103475/). I would like to create a stacked bar graph based on the following data:

```
initialData = [ {
          "name": "apples",
          "values": [{ "xInit": 0, "yInit": 91 }, { "xInit": 1, "yInit": 290 }, { "xInit": 2, "yInit": 120 }]
      },{
          "name": "oranges",
          "values": [{ "xInit": 0, "yInit": 9 }, { "xInit": 1, "yInit": 49 }, { "xInit": 2, "yInit": 37 }]
      }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do here so this isn't a full solution but I'll help you get going.

You can manipulate the outgoing data with the `out()` function to get the `x` coordinate you're looking for and thus make your graph happen.

```
var st = d3.layout.stack()
        .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
        .out(function(d, y0, y) {d.x = d.xInit; d.y0 = y0; d.y = y; })
        .y(function (v, i) { return v.yInit; });
```

Comment: That helps; when should I use the `out` function instead of the `x` function? Afaik the `out` function is used to specify "how to propagate the computed baseline to above layers". And the `x` function specifies "how to access the x-coordinate of each value's position".

Comment: stack() returns the data as an object which it has performed some transforms on using the `.x()` and `.y()` accessor. Once you've got the data back your code then assumes that `d.x` will be available when in fact it's only going to be `d.xInit` given what you have.  Essentially you seem to be treating it like a stack class when you really have inert data which has been transformed by the stack function.  You'll want to fix it by changing to access xInit or the out function to modify the data propagated.  I hope that makes sense.